# Export chart data to excelsheet

Tags: apache-flex, charts, blazeds, advanceddatagrid

I wanted to export chart data (coming from java services) to excel. Do I need to create datagrid for that.

Answer (score 1):

My preference, when needing to provide excel output, is to send the data to the server and generate the excel sheet there.

There is one library, named [as3xls](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/) which claims to read and write excel files from AS3; so I would recommend you look into that.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use as3xls on the client side and I created one example for that in cook book   here: [Import/Export](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Import_Export_data_in_out_of_a_Datagrid_in_Flex-17223.html). Also you can make use of Apache POI on Java layer as it provides more support for document generation.

You need not to create Datagrid for your chart. Your chart must be using some series (an array probably) to display that data. If you simply want to export that data into excel, you can create an ArrayCollection out of that and use as3xls. If your data contains come native alphabets/characters then as3xls may have some problem. In that case it is better to do it on server side.